# Bootstrap Pagination for product

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```html
 <div class="row">
   
   <?php getPro(); ?>
  <?php getCatPro(); ?>
   
   
    <nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
   
   </div>
```

I have created new website I added few sample items in the first page but I need to know if the new user add new product it should go to the next page itself or should I code to a new page. How I know exactly if more products fills more pages? Anyone know how to go about?

Comment: I think this depends more on the system you are using instead of bootstrap

Comment: Thanks Turqueso. Do you know any site to read how to use them that will help me?

Comment: I see some php tag, what are you using?

Comment: Im using php and sql only...

Comment: I don't know much about php but you should find more help about what you want to do in php and sql tags. Bootstrap is only for styling but It won't be able to know what on your database